# Hash character in WCF REST parameter

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a WCF service that accepts GET calls. 
I have a dropdown on my ui that has a list of road exits (exit #1, exit #2, etc.)
When the user selects an exit and mashes a button i call that service with the selected value.
It gets encoded and i can see in fiddler that the end of the url looks like this:

```
EXIT%20%231
```

which corresponds to a user selection of EXIT #1
When this param gets to the server, however, all i see in it is the term EXIT.
I think this is related to the hash character having a special meaning in WCF.
Changing that hash tag in my records is not an option. Is there another option to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

If you have text that is being messed with in transit, you could try base64 encoding before you send it, then decode on the server side.